# Conditional Uniformity of Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Assume a Poisson process with parameter 2. How do I compute $$P\{ N(1)=2, N(3) = 4 | N(5) = 6\}?$$ I know from conditional uniformity that we should have $$P\{N(1) = 2, N(2) = 2 | N(5)=6\}$$ so that 2+2 should be equal to 6. But here is the case that the condition is not satisfied.  I need help. Could there be a typo in the problem or there is a way around this problem?

Comment: what does $N(t)$ stand for? number of events by time $t$?

Comment: Yes $N(t)$ denotes the number of events at t

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of conditional probability to write your quantity as a ratio, the numerator is
$$
\eqalign{P[N(1)=2, & N(3)-N(1)=2, N(5)-N(3)=2]
\cr
&=P[N(1)=2]P[N(3)-N(1)=2]P[N(5)-N(3)=2]\cr
}
$$
The three probabilities on the right can be evaluated directly, resulting in a product of $128e^{-10}$. And the denominator is just ${10^6\over 6!}e^{-10}$.

Comment: interesting! i'm wondering if the two solutions agree

Answer (score 0):

If the number of events by time $5$ is 6, you have 6 events uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,5]$. Now,

$$P(N(1)=2, N(3)=4|N(5)=6) = P(N(3)=4|N(1)=2,N(5)=6) P(N(1)=2|N(5)=6)$$

Then, from memoryless property,

$$ P(N(3)=4|N(1)=2,N(5)=6) P(N(1)=2|N(5)=6)=P(N(2)=2|N(4)=4) P(N(1)=2|N(5)=6) $$

The first term equals the probability that the first 2 events from 4 uniform events in the interval [0,4] occur before 2.     I believe that by symmetry this equals 0.5

The second term equals the probability that the first 2 events from 6 uniform events in the interval [0,5] occur before 1.    I believe you can compute this from [conditional probability poisson process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733487/conditional-probability-poisson-process?rq=1)

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733487/conditional-probability-poisson-process?rq=1 Observed that the author provided a general case at the bottom where $S = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$. This is exactly what I meant earlier. This condition has to be meet.